# Bad parameters to mail() function issue in php email

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

error: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent. in /home/content/19/10977719/html/turgut/email/send.php on line 59

i'm trying to send mail with attachments. it shows error.

it works without attachment but i dont need it.

this is not working, same error: http://www.vivekmoyal.in/send-email-attachment-in-php-send-attachment-in-email-php/

this is my php code:

```
    $upload_name=$_FILES["upload"]["name"];
    $upload_type=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
    $upload_size=$_FILES["upload"]["size"];
    $upload_temp=$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"];

    $fp = fopen($upload_temp, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $upload_size);

    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
    $num = md5(time());     

$ad     = $_POST['ad'];   
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$r_email  = $_POST['r_email'];
$msg    = $_POST['msg'];
$subject    = $_POST['konu'];



       $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
       $headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
       $headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
       $headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

       // spamden kaçmak için bir yöntem

       $headers .= "Message-ID: <".gettimeofday()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
       $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";

                // With message

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
       $headers .= "".$msg."\n";
       $headers .= "--".$num."\n";

        // Attachment headers

    $headers  .= "Content-Type:".$upload_type." ";
       $headers  .= "name=\"".$upload_name."\"r\n";
       $headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $headers  .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
       $headers  .= "filename=\"".$upload_name."\"\r\n\n";
       $headers  .= "".$file."\r\n";
       $headers  .= "--".$num."--";

$mailsonuc = mail("$r_email","$subject","$msg", $headers);
```

this is html:

```
<form id="attach" name="attach" action="gonder.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1>{TOP_MSG}</h1>

            <table border="0" width="650">
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{NAME}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Adınız Soyadınız" required name="ad" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{SENDER}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="E-Posta Adresiniz" required name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{RECEIVER}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Alıcı E-Posta Adresi" required name="r_email" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{KONU}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><textarea name="konu"  required="" cols="46" rows="1"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{MESSAGE}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><textarea name="msg"  required="" cols="46" rows="7"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign=middle>{EK}</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td> <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>        

            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Gönder" id="send" name="send" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: One does not simply use `mail()` directly. You should consider a more robust/stable solution [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: It might help if you told us what the error you're seeing is.

Comment: Unless you're not showing us your entire code, your first `$headers` should not start with a dot. You have `$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";`. If that is in fact your first header, then remove the dot and replace with this `$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";`. (for one thing). Also, show us the code that is on line 59, also the lines before, and after it.

Comment: What is the reference to `$mailsonuc`? I only see it once in your posted code. You're obviously not showing us your entire code.

Comment: yeah there is 1 line before this code. 
it is: $headers  = "From: Info Mail<me@me.com>\r\n";
and
line 59: $mailsonuc=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: @guybennet You haven't defined the `$to` variable, that's probably why you're getting errors.

Comment: @guybennet You say line 59 is `$mailsonuc=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` yet your code reads as `$mailsonuc = mail("$r_email","$subject","$msg", $headers);`. **Which one is it?** **Change** `$mailsonuc=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` **to** `$mailsonuc = mail("$r_email","$subject","$msg", $headers);`, try it and get back to me.

Comment: @guybennet Or, add/define `$to` such as `$to = your_email@your_site.com;`

Comment: @guybennet another thing. I'm not going to continue re-checking this thread. If you're going to reply to my comments, add the **@** symbol including my name. I.e. **@Fred**.

Comment: @Fred now it sends mail but you cant open file. it sends same name and size. i think its broken

Comment: @guybennet What do you mean by *"it can't open the file and it sends same name and size"*? What are you trying to achieve; what are your expected results?

Comment: @Fred The e-mail was sent with an attached ,but the attachment gets corrupted. you cant open file.

Comment: @guybennet Sorry, but that's not a topic which I know much about. I suggest you post another question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you issues based on minor mistake only.

1. Check your PHP version
2. Mail your hosting company and report it to them.
3. Try removing the Bcc: Header's and see if that work's.

[simply search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+form+file+upload+and+email)

Refer this link too:

[This is example for fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136041/attachment-email-form-how-to-create-a-file-upload-form-to-send-with-email)

other wise, please don't build your own MIME emails. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), which do almost everything for you. You can replace you entire script with about 5 or 6 lines of code.
unless you can 
[Refer this links also](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed that I had HTML character `<p>` in the subject line. Once removed, it worked.